# How to avoid unsafe calls and create a better response models structure?

Tags: http, kotlin, retrofit, response

I'm trying to parse Spacex api request [Click here to see json structure](https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches/69). I've created a pojo models structure using Android studio plugin. Now it looks like [Click here to see](https://gitlab.com/fursa.ilya/spacex-tracker/-/tree/master/app%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Ffursa%2Fspacex%2Fapi%2Fmodel%2Flaunch)
I'm using this code for getting a necessary fields.   [image]

As you can see it's not so good. Could you please give me a tip how to avoid such code in my application and create a better response structure using Base classes and abstraction? The response structure has lots of nested classes.

Comment: Are you developing Android application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing android application, Use DataBinding and send `detail.rocket.secondStage.payload[0]` as model to it

Comment: idk how to do it better at the moment